# Conditionally treating/casting a base class reference parameter as a derived class and giving it back

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, casting, reinterpret-cast

I have a function, the signature or caller of which I cannot easily change, which gets a reference to a struct. This struct is of an base class, but depending on something which is discovered in this function, the struct is determined to be of an inherited type and manipulated as such. Later, this data will be dynamic_cast'd as appropriate, depending on how we set it up here.

```
struct Base {
    int baseMember;
}

struct Derived : public Base {
    int derivedMember;
}

enum EvtType {
    EVT_A,
    EVT_B
}

void handleEvent(Base& data) {
    data.baseMember++; //adjust the common member

    switch (getEventType()) // some static returning EvtType
    {
    case EVT_A:
        // I can instatiate this as required, setting baseMember in a constructor
        // or something
        Derived derivedInst;

        // and now i can set the derived members as needed
        derivedInst.derivedMember += 56; // this is just what happens with EVT_As

        // FIXME: but how do I get this object into the data parameter? 
        break;
    case EVT_B:
        // do it differently, but the same idea
        break;
    }
    //handle other event types
}
```

Is this possible with something like `reinterpret_cast`, even though the incoming reference's object has presumably already been allocated by someone else as a `Base`?

Also, depending on the contents of the cases in the switch, is there a tidier way to set up a mapping from `EvtType` to setting up the right derived class, considering that I can't extend the `Derived` or `Base` classes.

Comment: So you're basically asking, how to say `data = derivedInst;`? I don't believe this is possible unless the base class uses type erasure.

Comment: Why can't you do `static_cast<Derived&>(data).derivedMember += 56`? I don't really understand.

Answer (score 0):

As i understand you actually need to find out the real type of `data`. So, you can check it by `typeid` operator. See [***example***](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/typeinfo/type_info/operator==/). Hope this helps.